# Bash Script - If Pyscript Returns Non-zero, Write Errors to Output File AND Quite Bash Script

Tags: bash, pytest

Have the below in a bash script -

`python3 run_tests.py 2>&1 | tee tests.log`

If I run `python3 run_tests.py` alone, I can do the below to exit the script:

```
python3 run_tests.py

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
   echo 'ERROR: pytest failed, exiting ...'
   exit $?
```

However, the above working code doesn't write the output of pytest to a file.

When I run `python3 run_tests.py 2>&1 | tee tests.log`, the output of pytest will output to the file, but this always returns status 0, since the output job successfully ran.

I need a way to somehow capture the returned code of the python script tests prior to writing to the file. Either that, or something that accomplishes the same end result of quitting the job if a test fails while also getting the failures in the output file.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit status of a pipeline is the status of the last command, so `$?` is the status of `tee`, not `pytest`.

In `bash` you can use the `$PIPESTATUS` array to get the status of each command in the pipeline.

```
python3 run_tests.py 2>&1 | tee tests.log
status=${PIPESTATUS[0]} # status of run_tests.py
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'ERROR: pytest failed, exiting ...'
    exit $status
fi
```

Note that you need to save the status in another variable, because `$?` and `$PIPESTATUS` are updated after each command.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I tried to save the entire function in variable, and obviously ran into the same problem. Makes sense what you did here. I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes (which is when it'll let me!)

Comment: Oh, nice. Just noticed the adjustment. I didn't know about PIPESTATUS, that's great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have python on my system so using awk to produce output and a specific exit status instead:

```
$ { awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"; exit 1}'; ret="$?"; } > >(tee tests.log)
foo
$ echo "$ret"
1
$ cat tests.log
foo
```

or if you want a script:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#########
exec 3>&1                         # save fd 1 (stdout) in fd 3 to restore later

exec > >(tee tests.log)           # redirect stdout of this script to go to tee

awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"; exit 1}'  # run whatever command you want

ret="$?"                          # save that command's exit status

exec 1>&3; 3>&-                   # restore stdout and close fd 3
#########

echo "here's the result:"

echo "$ret"

cat tests.log
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
foo
here's the result:
1
foo
```

Obviously just test the value of `ret` to exit or not, e.g.:

```
if (( ret != 0 )); then
    echo 'the sky is falling' >&2
    exit "$ret"
fi
```

You could also wrap the command call in a function if you like:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doit() {
    local ret=0

    exec 3>&1                           # save fd 1 (stdout) in fd 3 to restore later
    exec > >(tee tests.log)             # redirect stdout of this script to go to tee

    awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"; exit 1}'    # run whatever command you want

    ret="$?"                            # save that command's exit status

    exec 1>&3; 3>&-                     # restore stdout and close fd 3

    return "$ret"
}

doit

echo "\$?=$?"
cat tests.log
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
foo
$?=1
foo
```